# Looping cut2 color argument in qplot

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, hmisc

First off fair warning that this is relevant to a quiz question from coursera.org practical machine learning. However, my question does not deal with the actual question asked, but is a tangential question about plotting.

I have a training set of data and I am trying to create a plot for each predictor that includes the outcome on the y axis, the index of the data set on the x axis, and colors the plot by the predictor in order to determine the cause of bias along the index. To make the color argument more clear I am trying to use `cut2()` from the Hmisc package.

Here is my data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(caret)
library(AppliedPredictiveModeling)
library(Hmisc)
data(concrete)
set.seed(1000)
inTrain = createDataPartition(mixtures$CompressiveStrength, p = 3/4)[[1]]
training = mixtures[ inTrain,]
testing = mixtures[-inTrain,]
training$index <- 1:nrow(training)
```

I tried this and it makes all the plots but they are all the same color.

```
plotCols <- function(x) { 
  cols <- names(x)
  for (i in 1:length(cols)) {
    assign(paste0("cutEx",i), cut2(x[ ,i]))
    print(qplot(x$index, x$CompressiveStrength, color=paste0("cutEx",i)))
  }
}
plotCols(training)
```

Then I tried this and it makes all the plots, and this time they are colored but the cut doesn't work.

```
plotCols <- function(x) { 
  cols <- names(x)
  for (i in 1:length(cols)) {
    assign(cols[i], cut2(x[ ,i]))
    print(qplot(x$index, x$CompressiveStrength, color=x[ ,cols[i]]))
  }
}
plotCols(training)
```

It seems `qplot()` doesn't like having `paste()` in the color argument. Does anyone know another way to loop through the color argument and still keep my cuts? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired output is easier to achieve using `ggplot()` instead of `qplot()`, since you can use `aes_string()`, that accepts strings as arguments.

```
plotCols <- function(x) { 
  cols <- names(x)
  for (i in 1:length(cols)) {
    assign(paste0("cutEx", i), cut2(x[, i]))

    p <- ggplot(x) +
         aes_string("index", "CompressiveStrength", color = paste0("cutEx", i)) +
         geom_point()

    print(p)
  }
}

plotCols(training)
```